# SearchWidget not calling onSearchRequested()

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-actionbar, android-searchmanager

I'm trying to implement `SearchWidget` correctly, but I'm facing up with some problems. I override `onSearchRequested()` because I need to pass some information's from the calling Activity to the `Activity` that executes the query.

It happens only when the `SearchWidget` looses its "focus". This is what I mean for "focused" `SearchWidget`:
[image: Focused SearchWidget]
If I search without touching outside the `SearchWidget` (and so with the focuses `SearchWidget`) `onSearchRequested()` is correctly called.
**BUT** when I touch outside the `SearchWidget` and it looses it focus, when I perform the search, the method `onSearchRequested()` is not called.
[image: SearchWidget without focus]

This is the code of `onSearchRequested`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_mainscreen, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            break;
        case R.id.mainscreen_favorites:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FavoritesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle appData = new Bundle();
    appData.putInt(Constants.EXTRA_CATEGORY, index);
    startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up by starting my search activity from SearchView.OnQueryTextListener using a normal Intent.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      startSearch(query);
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String s) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  private void startSearch(final String query) {
    // Doesn't call through onSearchRequest
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.CATALOG, getCatalogID());
    intent.putExtra(Keys.HAS_ARTICLES, hasArticles);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.QUERY, query);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
```